# PhP compare two arrays then write to file

Tags: php, arrays

I have inbound return data -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php that is in PhP array format. The file data is the same type. It is just $result from the previous cycle.

```
$result = api_query("mytrades", array("marketid" => $id));
```

How do I compare $result array with $file array and then over write FILE with $result data?
In other words, FILE and the data it contains is continuously being updated with $result

compare -> overwrite -> repeat at next execution.

I tried array_diff but it does not like my data types and I cannot find a work around.
Note: .db file is empty at first cycle but becomes populated at first write.

sample code with Array to string conversion error:

```
<?php
 $id = 155;
 require_once('phpPlay.php');
 $result = api_query("mytrades", array("marketid" => $id));
 $lines = file("myDB.db");
 $arrayDiffresult = array_diff ( $result, $lines);
 var_dump($result);
 file_put_contents('myDB.db', print_r($result, true));
?>
```

[var_dump($result);](https://bpaste.net/show/ae68bfe517c3)

Comment: and what does `$lines` contain?

Comment: at first (such as now) it is empty. on line 8, it 'will' contain $result

Comment: same error with test data in the file (copy/paste var_dump)

Comment: Do you need compare? or difference?

Comment: @alu difference  ->  array_diff when you compare, you know the difference.   :)  array_diff would do the trick, but I can't get it to work with my data types. If you know and alternate route to doing the same as above, that would be ideal.

Comment: What wrong? diffresult? We can't imaginate even what your api_query returns...

Comment: what it returns, is on the link var_dump($result). that is also the contents of file. same same

Comment: If you need compare only, just compare to `json_encode` result. But you need difference, need compare logic. these are not same.

Comment: @alu right now I am doing json_decode in phpPlay.php. Are you saying I should axe/wax/stop/cease json_decode there, allow the bare json string come in via $result and then do my comparison with that?  Can you show me what that would look like, assuming json_decode was disabled in phpPlay.php?

Comment: @brad, not, he say, that if you need only a flag (equals, not equals) - you can compare serialized strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you looking for some serialization, json_encoding for example.

```
$result = array(
    'return' => array(
        array(
            "tradeid"       =>"74038377",
            "tradetype"         =>"Sell",
            "datetime"      =>"2014-11-12 16:05:32",
            "tradeprice"        =>"0.00675000",
            "quantity"      =>"22.18670000",
            "fee"       =>"-0.00007488",
            "total"         =>"0.14976023",
            "initiate_ordertype"        =>"Buy",
            "order_id"      =>"197009493",
        ),
        array(
            "tradeid"       =>"2",
            "tradetype"         =>"Sell",
            "datetime"      =>"2014-11-12 16:05:32",
            "tradeprice"        =>"0.00675000",
            "quantity"      =>"22.18670000",
            "fee"       =>"-0.00007488",
            "total"         =>"0.14976023",
            "initiate_ordertype"        =>"Buy",
            "order_id"      =>"2",
        )
    )
);


function getdiff($new, $old)
{
    //implement right logical diff here
    $diff = array();
    $old_serialized = array();
    foreach ($old as $item) {
        $old_serialized[] = json_encode($item);
    }
    foreach ($new as $item) {
        if (in_array(json_encode($item), $old_serialized)) {
            continue;
        }
        $diff[] = $item;
    }
    return $diff;
}

$old = file_exists('1.db') ? json_decode(file_get_contents('1.db'), 1) : array();
$arrayDiffresult = getdiff($result['return'], $old);
file_put_contents('1.db', json_encode($result['return']));

print_r($arrayDiffresult);
```

Comment: Should I disable json_decode my phpPlay.php file?  https://bpaste.net/show/cfb20ea5d92e

Comment: no, I think you need php array to traverse it to find some new items in API response...

Comment: As you can see, I use `$result['return']` key :)

Comment: is this what you are talking about?  https://bpaste.net/show/051de68dcdd3 I am not getting the expected results. a blank

Comment: Check [this](https://bpaste.net/show/0c361a17cb0f). Instead last `print_r`, just check a file `1.db`

Comment: the following will continuously show the same print_r result of 199 sets as though the compare never occurs.   https://bpaste.net/show/080ea3d59451  and yes, the 1.db file 'is' populated with the correct data.  ->  [{"tradeid":"74038377","tradetype":"Sell"  .....

Comment: same with your code without using my $result but using yours. Same items are returned.

Comment: You need some more correct `getdiff` implementation than return `$new` obviously...

Comment: anyway I make this work for you(with my own assumptions about logic)... check the answer.

Comment: you code detects that there is a change, but not what the difference is. upon 2nd cycle of code, the output is an empty array() which is correct. That means they match. but upon editing one single element in the array, the output is the entire array (in full) again.

Comment: @brad, I can't to know your business logic. Try write it yourself

Comment: same thing as array_diff as indicated in the post.

Comment: then just call `array_diff` instead of the `getdiff`